# how to get the RGB value of a pixel inside the Form workspace

Tags: c#, macros, rgb, pixel

im creating a macro and need to check some pixels to make sure the mouse clicks the right spot. How wold you go about checking the RGB value of pixels in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after alot of testing this is what i enden up with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Color_tool
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Regex rgbInputR;
    Regex rgbInputG;
    Regex rgbInputB;

    Match R, G, B;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;


    string colorX;

    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);
    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    private static readonly IntPtr DesktopDC = GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero);

    public static System.Drawing.Color GetPixelAtCursor()
    {
        System.Drawing.Point p = Cursor.Position;
        return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(GetPixel(DesktopDC, p.X, p.Y));
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorX = GetPixelAtCursor().ToString();
        Color backX = GetPixelAtCursor();
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
        label1.Text = colorX;
        RGB_value();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled == false)
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        else
            timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void RGB_value()
    {
        rgbInputR = new Regex(@"(?<=R=)\d{0,3}");
        rgbInputG = new Regex(@"(?<=G=)\d{0,3}");
        rgbInputB = new Regex(@"(?<=B=)\d{0,3}");

        Match R, G, B;

        R = rgbInputR.Match(colorX);
        G = rgbInputG.Match(colorX);
        B = rgbInputB.Match(colorX);
        //had to flip the R and B ???
        b = int.Parse(R.Groups[0].Value);
        g = int.Parse(G.Groups[0].Value);
        r = int.Parse(B.Groups[0].Value);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking at the RGB values for a bitmap,

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img))
{
Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
MessageBox.Show(color.R.toString() + color.G.toString() + color.B.toString());
}
```